# Mock a lambda parameter in Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, lambda, mocking, moq

I would like to mock this action in Moq:

```
Action<string, long> cursorPersister;
```

I have tried to implemented in this way:

```
var cursorPersister = new Mock<Action<string, long>>();
cursorPersister.Setup(cp => cp.Invoke(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<long>()));

cursorPersister.Verify();
```

However it does not work. Program freeze on the line where I call Setup(...).
Anyone can explain this and offer an alternative approach?

Comment: I defined the cursorPersister like this: var cursorPersister = new Mock<Action<string, long>>();

Comment: What are you expecting to happen by mocking an Action?  Why not just make an action that does whatever you need for the test?

Comment: Mocks are generally used to save time on creating test implementations of complicated classes.  Defining an Action is quite simple however, so you shouldn't need to mock it.

Comment: @twu can you please clarify what exactly you are testing here? How this action is used by your real code?

Comment: The reason why I was trying to mock the Action instead of easily define the mocked Action is because I wanted to use Verify() to assert if the action has been called as expected. Does that make sense?

Comment: Verify will be something like this: cursorPersister.Verify(cp => cp.Invoke("key", 1));

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. 
Instead of

```
cursorPersister.Setup(cp => cp.Invoke(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<long>()));
```

Use

```
cursorPersister.Setup(cp => cp(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<long>()));
```

Answer (score -2):

Just create a method with a string and long parameters and pass it instead of the mock. Why do you want to mock it?

Comment: The reason why I was trying to mock the Action instead of easily define the mocked Action is because I wanted to use Verify() to assert if the action has been called as expected. Verify will be something like this: cursorPersister.Verify(cp => cp.Invoke("key", 1));